# function in list only works on the first list item in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm looping through a list, every list item has a arrow button that can show a hidden div underneath it. But right now every button triggers the first item in the list.
Im working right now in react, but i cant find the right solution

My JS react file

```
const CardConference = ({ content }) => {

    const showItems = () => {
        const items = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-items")[0];
        const arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down")[0]

        if (items.style.display == "block") {
            items.style.display = "none";
            arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

        } else {
            items.style.display = "block";
            arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="card card-conferences ">
            <h4> {content[0].title} </h4>
            <ul>
                {content[0].cities.map((city) => (
                    <div>
                        <li className="city-name"> {city.name}
                            <button className="btn button-arrow" onClick={showItems} ><FaAngleDown color="#717171" className="arrow-down" /></button>
                        </li>
                        <ul className="hidden-items">
                            {city.conferenties.map((conf) => (
                                <li className="hidden-item">{conf} </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div >
    );
}

export default CardConference;
```

And this is my css

```
.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin-left: -6px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotate-arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

..hidden-items {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you're using react then why are you manipulating the dom yourself? You can use react itself to show/hide elements and add/remove classes.

Comment: Seems like the wrong way to do things in React

Answer (score 0):

Because you only get getElementsByClassName for first element. You need to pass an index to get exactly the element.

```
const showItems = (i) => () => {
    const items = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-items")[i];
    const arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down")[i]
    ...


cities.map((city, index)
...
onClick={showItems(index)}
...
```